# Remove list of repetitions in a list SQL

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table for a game where more people play the game it will repeat each other.. I can remove duplicates no problem but this one is different because I want to remove the others while keeping the highest score is it possible to do it?

for example

```
Name   Level Score
Green  99    797,000
Green  99    819,000
Green  99    970,000
Green  99    890,000
```

I want to keep row 3 and remove the others.

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you're asking or what you're trying to accomplish, sorry. Maybe you can post a little more information about the functionality you're trying to code?

Comment: SELECT TOP 1 FROM [table] ORDER BY Score DESC

Comment: wow the down votes, maybe I choosen the wrong place to ask a question yea. thank you all. keep down voting until -1 million I guess

Comment: @Mark, that's Microsoft SQL Server syntax, not MySQL.

Comment: @BillKarwin guess why I added comment and not answer. This is the solution **IF** I understood the problem correctly, syntax is something the asker can figure out on his own (the question is sloppy, the answer is sloppy, that was my deal). EDIT: thanks for posting my solution as an answer. That's the way to earn points indeed! GZ

Comment: @mark you aren't helpful so peace..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example you show, you can get the top row this way:

```
SELECT * FROM `thistable` ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 1
```

But I assume you have more than one Name in the table. If you want the highest score for a specific name:

```
SELECT * FROM `thistable` WHERE Name = 'Green' ORDER BY Score DESC LIMIT 1
```

If you want results for multiple names, but the row with the highest score for each one, it's a bit more complex:

```
SELECT * FROM `thistable` 
JOIN (SELECT Name, MAX(Score) AS Score FROM `thistable` GROUP BY Name) AS x
  USING (Name, Score);
```

This type of problem is commonly tagged [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) and it's a frequent question.

PS: Don't take the downvotes seriously. Stack Overflow has become a pretty nasty place. There will always be someone who thinks you didn't ask a valid question, or didn't ask it "correctly."